# Every derived table must have its own alias error

Tags: sql, mysql

I get that error when running the following query:

```
SELECT MAX( DateTime )
FROM (
(
    SELECT DateTime
    FROM Class_Searches
)
UNION ALL (
    SELECT DateTime
    FROM Book_Searches
)
)
WHERE User_Email = 'bla@blah.com'
AND DateTime > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

I know I need to add Aliases but I'm not sure where

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need an alias for the subquery, and you need to apply the conditions either to both queries that you union:

```
SELECT MAX(DateTime)
FROM (

  SELECT DateTime
  FROM Class_Searches
  WHERE User_Email = 'bla@blah.com'
  AND DateTime > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DateTime
  FROM Book_Searches
  WHERE User_Email = 'bla@blah.com'
  AND DateTime > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY

) AS x
```

or return data so that you can apply the condition in the outer query:

```
SELECT MAX(DateTime)
FROM (

  SELECT DateTime, User_Email
  FROM Class_Searches

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DateTime, User_Email
  FROM Book_Searches

) AS x
WHERE User_Email = 'bla@blah.com'
AND DateTime > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

An alias is when you rename something, like `SELECT t.time from table t`, `t` is the alias for that table.  In this case, you need to give an alias to the tables generated by the subqueries:

```
SELECT MAX( ut.DateTime )
FROM (
(
    SELECT DateTime
    FROM Class_Searches
) cs
UNION ALL (
    SELECT DateTime
    FROM Book_Searches
) bs
) ut
WHERE User_Email = 'bla@blah.com'
AND ut.DateTime > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

That still won't work though, because you don't have a User_Email column returned from the UNION.  Thus, try:

```
SELECT MAX( ut.DateTime )
FROM (
(
    SELECT DateTime, User_Email
    FROM Class_Searches
) cs
UNION ALL (
    SELECT DateTime, User_Email
    FROM Book_Searches
) bs
) ut
WHERE ut.User_Email = 'bla@blah.com'
AND ut.DateTime > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

It's possible that that still won't work right because of the UNION syntax, but at least it's a lot closer.

Comment: I get this error with the second query:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'bs
) ut
WHERE ut.User_Email = 'bla@blah.com'
AND ut.DateTime > NOW( ) - INTER' at line 10