# Every derived table must have its own alias, but alias given to all sub-queries gives error

Tags: mysql, subquery, relational-database, alias

The following MySQL query on a relational database generates the error "Every derived table must have its own alias". Based on [every derived table must have its own alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias) and [Every derived table must have its own alias error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436009/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-error). I give aliases to every table in sub-queries and the resultant table of the unions. Yet that did not seem to fix it. Can someone explain what is still missing in here?

```
SELECT major
FROM
    (SELECT major, count(*) amount
    FROM
            (((SELECT major
            FROM
                    (SELECT tutorID
                    FROM questionAnsweredBy
                    AS t1)
                    NATURAL JOIN
                    (SELECT tutorID, major
                    FROM tutor
                    AS t2) AS t12
            )
            AS t3
            UNION
            (SELECT major
            FROM
                    (SELECT tutorID
                    FROM expertAnswerGivenBy
                    AS t4)
                    NATURAL JOIN
                    (SELECT tutorID, major
                    FROM tutor
                    AS t5) AS t13
            )
            AS t6) AS t15
            UNION
            (SELECT major
            FROM
                    (SELECT tutorID
                    FROM textbookSolutionGivenBy
                    AS t7)
                    NATURAL JOIN
                    (SELECT tutorID, major
                    FROM tutor
                    AS t8) AS t14
            )
            AS t9) AS t16
    GROUP BY major
    AS t10
    )
AS t11
```

Comment: I don't see aliases applied to the subqueries immediately before each `NATURAL JOIN`.

Comment: I believe t1, t4, and t7 are aliases for those queries right?

Comment: No, those are aliases for the `questionAnsweredBy`, `expertAnswerGivenBy` and `textbookSolutionGivenBy` tables *within* the subqueries. They're not aliases for the subqueries themselves (subquery aliases appear *after* the closing bracket that encloses the subquery.

Comment: No [mcve]. So we can't run this, or parts of it.

Comment: There is no point to your `group by`-`count` & outermost `select` since the latter just undoes the former. Is that a mistake or is this just a syntax experiment or work in progress etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NATURAL JOIN` right hand argument subqueries lack aliases. The subqueries that are arguments to the `UNION`s should not have aliases.

A `FROM` argument is `table` or `table [AS] alias` or `(select ...) [AS] alias`. Very common is to use `AS` in `SELECT` clauses for columns but not use it in `FROM` clauses for tables/subqueries. (Not all DBMSs support the latter.) You can chain `UNION`s without parentheses, as with`JOIN`s.

Let's align a subquery's parentheses vertically. Let's vertically align `SELECT`, `FROM`, `JOIN`, `UNION` & `GROUP BY` with arguments indented.

When you want to understand something technical, [start with the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

```
SELECT major
FROM
    (SELECT major, count(*) AS amount
    FROM
        (
            (SELECT major
            FROM
                (SELECT tutorID
                FROM questionAnsweredBy t1
                ) nj1
            NATURAL JOIN
                (SELECT tutorID, major
                FROM tutor t2
                ) t12
            )
        UNION
            (SELECT major
            FROM
                (SELECT tutorID
                FROM expertAnswerGivenBy t4
                ) nj2
            NATURAL JOIN
                (SELECT tutorID, major
                FROM tutor t5
                ) AS t13
            )
        UNION
            (SELECT major
            FROM
                (SELECT tutorID
                FROM textbookSolutionGivenBy t7
                ) nj3
            NATURAL JOIN
                (SELECT tutorID, major
                FROM tutor t8
                ) t14
            )
        ) t16
    GROUP BY major
    ) t10
```

**PS** Re simplifying further:

There is no point to your `group by`-`count(*)` & outermost `select` since the latter just undoes the former. Anyway all the `count(*)`s are 1 because `major` is unique in the `union` result.

For `from` arguments that are base table names you don't need to `select`. And you don't need an alias. Especially if you never dot it. You also don't need a `from` subselect alias to differ from its ancestor `from`s' aliases. It's common to use some standard name/prefix suggesting an unused alias, eg `x` or `dummy`.

You seem to be mapping from relational algebra to SQL. Presumably your base tables have no duplicate rows, duplicate columns or `null`s. You might as well `select * from` `join`s unless you want the `select` to represent a projection. Ideally use `union corresponding` but if it's not supported then explicitly list column names so they're paired correctly; either always or where columns can be in different order. You need to remove duplicates via `select distinct`; either always or where duplicates can arise--`select`ing on a non-superkey.

```
SELECT major
FROM
    (SELECT major, count(*) AS amount
    FROM
        (
            (SELECT major
            FROM questionAnsweredBy
            NATURAL JOIN tutor
            )
        UNION
            (SELECT major
            FROM expertAnswerGivenBy
            NATURAL JOIN tutor
            )
        UNION
            (SELECT major
            FROM textbookSolutionGivenBy
            NATURAL JOIN tutor
            )
        ) x
    GROUP BY major
    ) x
```